# Django pure controller functions

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller

I am wondering on how to implement pure controller functions in a Django's' "biased" MVC scheme. Let me explain it on an example.

Let's say I have a model of an Invoice, which has some attributes (say net, gross etc.). I can present it to the user using a view + template. And that's fine and easy.

But now, I want to send this invoice to a client. This is a more complicated thing, inluding more models (i.e. create an addressed `Package` model, get a number and let's say few other thing including creating and modifying not only `Invoice` model itself, but also creating and updating few other model types and instances.

I want this "action" to be available in multiple places of my web application, so going by the book I need to create a view with those actions implemented and bind it to some URL. Probably it should be implemented in POST action.

My questions are:

1. What kind of generic view should it be (*just* `View`? `DetailView`? other?).
2. Where should this View redirect after succesfull "send"? The simplest answer would be to redirect to the same referring page, but is this a correct way?
3. What if I want this "action" to be ran in background (say, send all unsend invoices at midnight) using celery or such? Of course I can make this a celery task and call it in a view. But is this clean django'ish solution? Where do you store such pure business methods in an app/project?

Comment: I don't know if this question is within the scope of stack overflow. It's more about opinions than objective facts.

I usually create a file called `tasks.py` for this kind of stuff. I don't use classes for this, only plain functions. Tasks can be called from your views, or with celery, or triggered from django's signals framework.